# Find $a_n$ and $b_n$, such that $M_n=a_nY_n+b_n$ defines a Martingale, when $E[Y_{n+1}|F_n]=u_nY_n+v_n$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales, filtrations

> Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a propability space and $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}=:\mathbb{F}$ a filtration. Let $Y_0,Y_1,\dots$ be a adapted process of integrable random variables. Further let $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be real-valued sequences, such that:
> $$E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=u_nY_n+v_n\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
> Now try to find two  real-valued sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that $M_n=a_nY_n+b_n$ defines a Martingale $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$.

I try to define $a_n$ and $b_n$ out of the property of the Martingale, that the conditional expected value of the next observation, given all the past observations, is equal to the most recent observation. According to that:
$$\begin{align}E[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]&=E[a_{n+1}\cdot Y_{n+1}+b_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]\\&=a_{n+1}\cdot E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]+b_{n+1}\\&=a_{n+1}(u_nY_n+v_n)+b_{n+1}\\&=\underbrace{(a_{n+1}u_n)}_{\substack{=:a_n}}\cdot Y_n+\underbrace{(a_{n+1}v_n+b_{n+1})}_{\substack{=:b_n}}=M_n \end{align}\\\Rightarrow a_n=\begin{cases} &\frac{a_{n-1}}{u_{n-1}} \text{ if } u_{n-1}\neq0 \\  & 0 \text{ ,else }   \end{cases}\wedge b_n=b_{n-1}-a_n\cdot v_{n-1}$$

In such a way the sequence $M_n$ would be proper defined
and would fulfill the martingale-property mentioned above.
Because $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a adapted process to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ the $M_n=a_nY_n+b_n$ sould also be a adapted process to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ (**Is this correct? And if yes: how can i proof it?**).
So it remains to show that the expected value $E(|M_n|)$ is finite for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (... or rather that $\{M_n\}\in\mathcal{L}^1$ intgrable).
Now it is a requirement that the $(Y_n)$ are integrable, whith that $(Y_n)\in\mathcal{L}^1$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Hence follows from linearity of the integration that $a_n\cdot Y_n+b_n=M_n$ must be integrable, too.

Is this correct so far? Or do I make it too easy for me when it comes to the point that $M_n$ is adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$?

Any assistance or thoughts would be much appreciated.

***EDIT:*** Claim:

> "If $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is adapted to $\mathbb{F}$, then $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}=(a_nY_n+b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is also adapted to $\mathbb{F}$.

Because $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is adapted to $\mathbb{F}$ we know that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $Y_n:(\Omega,\Sigma)\rightarrow(E\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathcal{E})$ is $\mathcal{F_n}$-$\mathcal{E}$-measurable. Meaning: $\forall A\in\mathcal{E}:Y_n^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}_n $.
Lets take a closer look at $a_nY_n+b_n=M_n:(\Omega,\Sigma)\rightarrow(E',\mathcal{E}':=\{M_n(B)|B\in\mathcal{E}\})$. Surely $E'=a_n\cdot E+b_n$ applies and $\mathcal{E}'\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, too. Let $A'\in\mathcal{E}'$. Then there exists a $A\in\mathcal{E}$, such that $A'=M_n(A)$. Therefor $M_n^{-1}(A')=Y_n^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{F}_n$ (because $Y_n$ is $\mathcal{F_n}$-$\mathcal{E}$-measurable). Thus is $M_n$ $\mathcal{F_n}$-$\mathcal{E'}$-measurable and accordingly is $M_n$ adapted to $\mathbb{F}$.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: Why do you think that the filtration is given by $\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_n)$?

Comment: Just define $a_n$ such that $a_n = a_{n-1}/u_{n-1}$ if $u_{n-1} \neq 0$, else $a_n = 0$.

Comment: @Proxava: because in the requirements the $(Y_n)$ are adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$. And if the $Y_n$ are adapted, $M_n=a_nY_n+b_n$ should also be adapted.

Comment: @DaviBarreira: That was the first thing i thought about, to get it at least somehow usefull defined. I'll change my Question accordingly.

Comment: @n3ckbeard-wizzard in the beginning you are given a filtration and then you deduce with black magic (to me) that it needs to be $\{\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_n)\}_n$. I think you should not touch the filtration-

Comment: @Proxava: I do not quite understand. In the prerequisites it is given that $(Y_n)$ is an adapted sequence to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$. So it seems appropriate to set $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ as $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: @n3ckbeard-wizzard The problem is that $\mathcal F_n$ may be larger than $\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_n)$.  It probably won't matter for this problem, but in general you can't just reduce the size of your filtration.

Comment: @user6247850 Ohh sure I understand. This is correct: The fact that  $(Y_n)$ is adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ just gives us that $\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\subseteq\mathcal{F}_n$.